# Boton ir hacia atras

Tags: android, android-layout

que puedo usar para que al dar click en el botón de atrás en Android me lleve a un fragment que yo escoja. Me explico, estoy en una pantalla, y la hacer click en atrás, me lleve a otra pero que no sea la anterior, sino otra.

Codigo

```
public class BP_ColesBruselas extends Fragment {


public BP_ColesBruselas() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view;

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bp__coles_bruselas, container, false);

    return view ;
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new Bajar_Peso()).commit();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: Muestranos tu codigo donde usas las `FragmentTransaction` y puedes recibir ayuda.

Comment: ¿Si no quieres que sea a la anterior, a cuál entonces? Puedes explicarte mejor y enseñarnos tu código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: a "otra pantalla", te refieres Activty o Fragment?

Comment: me refiero a un fragment,  creo que con un onKeyDown se podria hacer, pero tengo un error al poner el metodo en el fragment. Añado codigo del frgament

Comment: puedes mostrar tu contenedor... la actividad en la que se cargan ambos fragments

Answer (score 0):

Algo mas o menos asi amigo por lo que se puede enternder

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            TuFragment tufragment = new TuFragment ();
            tufragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "tutag");
            return true;


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo no se mucho de Android pero quizás te pueda servir lo que te diré.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    //Aqui puedes masndar llamar una funcion en tu activity principal
    //la cual infla todos los fragments
    infla_fragments("back");
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Después en la función puedes tener un switch con la función

```
public infla_fragments(String info){
  switch (info){
    TuFragment tufragment = new TuFragment ();
    tufragment.inflate(getActivity().getFragmentManager());
  }
}
```

Algo así no entiendo mucho de Android y casi no he trabajado con Android. Espero poder haberte ayudado.